# added a props onPress in that I am calling an event handleEvent. but nothing printing inside the method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to implement a textbox similar to google flights.
- so I have built a react autocomplete prototype.
- but in that i am facing an issue.
- right now in the google flights textbox when I click on the textbox it shows all the rersults without typing anything.
- but in my case if I type something only it will show the results.
- so the textbox I added a props onPress in that I am calling an event handleEvent.
- but nothing printing inside the method.
- can you tell me how to achieve so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/xp6x167kq4

[image]

```
 handleEvent = () => {
    console.log("I was clicked");
    alert("I was clicked");
  };


  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput
      }
    } = this;

    let suggestionsListComponent;

    if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
      if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <ul class="suggestions">
            {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              let className;

              // Flag the active suggestion with a class
              if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                className = "suggestion-active";
              }

              return (
                <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                  {suggestion}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <div class="no-suggestions">
            <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
          onPress={this.handleEvent}
          //onPress={this.handleEvent}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Comment: There is no `onPress` event in HTML. Did you mean [`onKeyPress`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)?

Comment: Try onFocus instead of onPress

Comment: @aseferov hey even though if I used onFocus, I am still not able to display the results on the textbox, providing my updated code here   https://codesandbox.io/s/xp6x167kq4

Comment: @aseferov hey for onFocus alone why we are using this before handleEvent, but not for other methods...it would be great if you let me know...so that I can learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because in your initial state you've written

```
this.state = {
  activeSuggestion: 0,
  filteredSuggestions: [],
  showSuggestions: false,
  userInput: '',
};
```

and later you run

`if (showSuggestions && userInput)` but on an initial click userInput still equals `''` which equates to false. Underneath again, you run `if (filteredSuggestions.length)` which also equates 0 because when nothing is typed the array filteredSuggestions is empty.

`console.log('' == true)` => `false` also
`console.log([].length == true)` => `false`

Comment: hey for onFocus alone why we are using this before handleEvent, but not for other methods...it would be great if you let me know...so that I can learn

Comment: sorry for late response...I went through your code changes and found that you had made changes in componentDidMount and added this if condition if (this.state.active) { , can you give comments to your code changes its very hard to understand :(

Comment: hey I looked again at your code changes...still not working...can you please help